# My service does not loop

Tags: c#

It is my first program for service.
If i run this code as Console, LOOP works, but if I convert it to service, it does the operation initially, but does not LOOP.
Could you help me correct it?
tnx

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using KICBservice;
using System.Data;
using ConsoleApplication1.Classes;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace KICBService
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class MyWindowsServiceInstaller : Installer
    {
        public MyWindowsServiceInstaller()
        {
            var processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            var serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

            //set the privileges
            processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

            serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "KICB_Payment";
            serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual;

            //must be the same as what was set in Program's constructor
            serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "KICB_Payment";

            this.Installers.Add(processInstaller);
            this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
        }
    }

    class Program : ServiceBase
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new Program());

            KICBservice.Service1SoapClient kicb = new KICBservice.Service1SoapClient();

            kicb.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("register", "KICBregistr1");
            kicb.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    kicb.Open();
                    StreamWriter tw = File.AppendText("c:\\KICB.log");

                    NewPayment np = new NewPayment();

                    np = kicb.GetPayment("register", "KICBregistr1");

                    // Operation with Database

                    tw.WriteLine("----------------");
                    tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
                    tw.Close();

                    kicb.Close();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    kicb.Abort();
                }
            }

        }

        public Program()
        {
            this.ServiceName = "KICB_Payment";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            base.OnStart(args);

            //TODO: place your start code here
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            base.OnStop();

            //TODO: clean up any variables and stop any threads
        }
    }
}
```

I am pasting full code of my program.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is permissions on the service. Have you tried debugging it (or at least checking the event log) to see what is going on?

Comment: It does some operation when I start the service. The problem is it does not loop+

Comment: Are you sure it is getting to loop the first time? The answers that have been proposed (and your comments on them) seem to lean toward the point that running your code as a service isn't doing anything at all. Attach a debugger and prove otherwise.

Comment: If I start/restart service, it writes to "c:\\KICB.log".

Comment: Perhaps but that instance of your program should die immediately (assuming it is setup as a console app). Check task manager after the entry is written to the log, are you sure the service is still running?

Comment: Attach to process and break it. Are there any thread running your program code?

Comment: I pasted here full code, I have no threads to run it. I install it with installUtil.exe

Comment: Every program has threads whether you start them or not. ;)

Comment: Hmm, I will study this part more deeply.

Answer (score 2):

Where is that first code located?

Without that context, my best guess is that your OnStart() method fires, and then the service quits as soon the method ends because there's nothing left to do.

Also, I'm not a fan of the `while (true) { Sleep(60000); // do work }` pattern for services. Instead, you want to look for a function that actually *blocks* execution to keep your code going. Examples include `TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()` and `Thread.Join()`. If you can't find something like that for the meat of your service, you may want to do something like set up a scheduled task instead.

Comment: @user998878 - Windows Services don't have `Main`'s per say.

Comment: I pasted full code of my program. Sorry if I explain in wrong

Answer (score 0):

You've placed the code outside of a function. What you have shown in the question should not even compile, and it certainly won't loop.

Note the `//TODO:` comment in the `OnStart` function definition:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    base.OnStart(args);

    //TODO: place your start code here
}
```

Comment: So, I should put that loop inside OnStart () ?